# loadFixtures not working for me in Jasmine in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, jasmine, handlebars.js

In my Rails app in `spec/javascripts/backbone/albums_spec.js`, I have the following spec...

```
describe('Albums collection', function() {
  it("fetches a collection of three albums", function(done) {

    loadFixtures('index.html');

    var albumsLoaded = App.albumsLoaded;
    App.albumsLoaded = function() {
      albumsLoaded.apply(App, arguments);
      expect(App.albums.models.length).toBe(3);
      expect(typeof App.albums.models[0].attributes.title).toBe("string");
      done();
    };

    App.init();
  });
});
```

When I run `$ rake teaspoon files=spec/javascripts/backbone/albums_spec.js`, I get the following failure...

`Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined` which is because in `assets/javascripts/backbone/views/albums.js`, I'm trying to compile a Handlebars template using an element from an html file...works fine in the browser, etc, but in the jasmine testing, I'm thinking I'll need to create an html fixture to simulate that html file.  So, in `spec/javascripts/fixtures/index.html`, I've pasted in that same html.  I've bundle-installed the `teaspoon-jasmine` and the `jasmine-jquery-rails` gems.  Unfortunately, I ALSO get this failure...

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: loadFixtures...`  I'm not able to load the html fixture I need in order to prevent that previously mentioned failure where nothing was passed into `Handlebars.compile`.  I've scoured through similar SO posts and github forums regarding this issue, but to no avail so far.  Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I actually got `loadFixtures ` to work, using `//= require ../helpers/jasmine_jquery.js` in `spec/javascripts/backbone/albums_spec.js`, so I guess my **real** problem is to figure out how to get that string into `Handlebars.compile` in `albums.js`.  Using `loadFixtures('index.html');` in `albums_spec.js` does not provide that string.

Comment: In my Backbone view, I changed `template: Handlebars.compile($("[data-name=albums]").html()),` to `template: function() { return Handlebars.compile($("[data-name=albums]").html()); },`. This enabled the spec above to pass.  But now I still have the same problem of `Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined` in another spec. I'm able to `loadFixtures('index.html');` into that spec, but I still get that error. Is there anything that I'm missing with this?  Thanks.